# Error: Expected private key to be an Uint8Array with length 32

Tags: truffle, javascript, truffle-migration

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
require('dotenv').config();
const privateKeys = [`0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}`]
```

this is my code in truffle-config.js but its not working

I am using the `.env` file where i have saved my private key of **MetaMask**

Comment: try to put it as shell environment variable, with `export PRIVATE_KEY="0x1111222333"`

Comment: It still throws the same error again

Comment: then I would probably run the javascript virtual machine with `strace` command to see all the system calls of `open` type and get the exact name of the `.env` file which the javascript vm is trying to open. this way you will find the location of the `.env` file with 100% certainty

Comment: or maybe it expects private key of length 64 hex, but you put it with 0x at the beginning, and it is 66 characters. For the private key to be 32 bytes the hex must be 64 characters long

Comment: even after removing the 0x in front of the line it throws the same error

Comment: then it is looking at wrong file, doesn't find anything and shows you this error. you will have to `strace` the process to figure out what's the exact file name is